# vercel No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vercel, http-status-code-500

I'm trying to deploy backend with vercel, but I get "500: internal server error" after deploying like this
[img 500 internal server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDMfN.png)
and "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." after i tried the API like this
[cors error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLvIz.png)

i also implemented cors in index.js like this
[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SzwV.png), but still got cors error

does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: You cannot add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to your Vercel domain address, because Vercel does not use it for edge functions. For correctly setting CORS, please [see](https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-enable-cors).